# Flex items at the top are cut off

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

My problem is that flex items are cut off at the top when the div overflows. I've tried many things but couldn't get over this problem. Thank you for helping!

Here is a [JSFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ap95y4t/2/) showing the problem:

```css
#root{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#flex-container{
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-child{
  width: 235px;
  height: 235px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-child">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-child">
    </div>
     <div class="flex-child">
    </div>
     <div class="flex-child">
    </div>
     <div class="flex-child">
    </div>
     <div class="flex-child">
    </div>
     <div class="flex-child">
    </div>
     <div class="flex-child">
    </div>
     <div class="flex-child">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: The problem is `align-content: center`, as described in the duplicate post.

Comment: But if a delete align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; as mentioned in the duplicate post, my flex items are not centered anymore what should I do?

Comment: Just `align-content`. And there are two solutions mentioned in the post.

Comment: You will need `.loader span:nth-child(1)' with keyframes and everything like that